# Casting ExceptionLoggerContext to HttpContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've written an Exception logger implementing the `System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionLogger` class.

We have a generic Exception Logging services, one of the implementations is for RayGun. Which uses `HttpContext.Current` as can be seen here:
https://github.com/MindscapeHQ/raygun4net/blob/master/Mindscape.Raygun4Net/RaygunClient.cs on line **337**.

```
public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
{
    HttpContext.Current = ...;
    ExceptionService.LogException(context.Exception);            
}
```

Is it possible to convert / cast:
`System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionLoggerContext` to `System.Web.HttpContext`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        HttpContext httpContext = GetHttpContext(context.Request);
        ExceptionService.LogException(context.Exception);
    }

    private static HttpContext GetHttpContext(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpContextBase contextBase = GetHttpContextBase(request);
        if (contextBase == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return contextBase.ApplicationInstance.Context;
    }

    private static HttpContextBase GetHttpContextBase(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        object value;

        if (!request.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_HttpContext", out value))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return value as HttpContextBase;
    }
```

copied from [here](http://helloworldbasic.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/aspnet-web-api-handle-and-log-exception.html)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't cast it, but you can use the `RequestContext` property of 
[ExceptionLoggerContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.exceptionhandling.exceptionloggercontext(v=vs.118).aspx).